# For the set, $\{(x,y]): 1≤ ∣x∣ ≤2,∣y−3∣ ≤2\}$ give two points in the set for which the line segment joining them goes outside the set.

Tags: linear-algebra

For the set, $\{(x,y]): 1≤ ∣x∣ ≤2,∣y−3∣ ≤2\}$ 
give two points in the set for which the line segment joining them goes outside the set.

Comment: have you tried drawing some pictures? That's the easiest approach (in my opinion) to forming an idea for how to prove something like this

Comment: As @Shanye2020 mentioned, plot the following three regions:

1) |x|>=1
2) |x|<=2
3) |y-3|<=2

Take the intersection of the three regions. This will give you the region of the set. Take a point inside that region and another point outside that region.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, initially i had trouble plotting the regions but after following the steps to divide into 3 regions I was able to plot it, Thanks @user2808118.

Answer (score 0):

The points $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ belong to the set, $(0,1)$ does not belong to the set.

Your turn !

Comment: This is an answer to the question ! The line segment joining $(1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ contains the point $(0,1)$. Hence , the line segment goes outside the set.